# Blueimp - How to upload from an image or link

Tags: jquery, file, upload, blueimp

I am trying to get blueimp file uploader to replace an already existing system.

Currently the one I am using allows me to click on an image (or a link) to upload a new file.

I cant quite figure out how to do the same thing with blueimp.

What do I need to do to trigger file upload by clicking on an image, link or some other element ID?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your question, but perhaps a solution to your problem.

May I suggest switching to Ravishanker Kusuma's [jQuery Upload File Plugin](http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php)? I've tried a bunch of file upload plugins, including blueimp, and really found Ravi's the best. Use it in all my projects. Try his example (link above) - it's dead simple.

Regardless which plugin you use, replacing an existing file will be done in the PHP file. In Ravi's plugin, it is named here:

```
url:"YOUR_FILE_UPLOAD_URL",
```

For example:

```
$("#fileuploader").uploadFile({
    url: "some_php_file.php",
    fileName:"myfile"
});
```

That PHP file will look something like this:

```
<?php
    $output_dir = "uploads/";
    if(isset($_FILES["myfile"])) {
        $ret = array();

    //  This is for custom errors;  
    /*  $custom_error= array();
        $custom_error['jquery-upload-file-error']="File already exists";
        echo json_encode($custom_error);
        die();
    */

        $error =$_FILES["myfile"]["error"];
        //You need to handle  both cases
        //If Any browser does not support serializing of multiple files using FormData() 
        if(!is_array($_FILES["myfile"]["name"])) //single file
        {
            $fileName = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir.$fileName);
            $ret[]= $fileName;
        }
        else  //Multiple files, file[]
        {
          $fileCount = count($_FILES["myfile"]["name"]);
          for($i=0; $i < $fileCount; $i++)
          {
            $fileName = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"][$i];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"][$i],$output_dir.$fileName);
            $ret[]= $fileName;
          }

        }
        echo json_encode($ret);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do cross domain posting? How about if REST APIs used?

Comment: I don't know about this except for what I have read. The other domain must allow the posting, but I don't know how that works. Continue to google, or post a question. Be sure to include some code so you are not drive-by-downvoted-into-oblivion. *Bon chance*